# command line arguments array

Tags: c#, command-line

I am having a command line arguments as like this I need to get the two as like this how is it possible

ApplicationId =1; Name =2

I like to get the two values 1,2 in single array how to do this.

Comment: You could probably help us by clarifying the question... it isn't 100% clear what the args look like or what you want to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
string values = "ApplicationId =1; Name =2";
string[] pairs = values.Split(';');

string value1 = pairs[0].Split('=')[1];
string value2 = pairs[1].Split('=')[1];
```

You'll need better error checking of course, but value1 and value2 should be "1" and "2" respectively

Answer (score 6):

It isn't entirely clear to me, but I'm going to assume that the arguments are actually:

```
 ApplicationId=1 Name=2
```

the spacing etc is important due to how the  system splits arguments. In a `Main(string[] args)` method, that will be an array length 2. You can process this, for example into a dictionary:

```
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        Dictionary<string, string> options = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        foreach (string arg in args)
        {
            string[] pieces = arg.Split('=');
            options[pieces[0]] = pieces.Length > 1 ? pieces[1] : "";
        }

        Console.WriteLine(options["Name"]); // access by key

        // get just the values
        string[] vals = new string[options.Count];
        options.Values.CopyTo(vals, 0);
    }
```

Comment: Yep, that's pretty much what I do for utilities that require named arguments.

Answer (score 2):

There's some good libraries mentioned on [631410](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/631410/looking-for-a-command-line-argument-parser-for-net) and [491595](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/491595/best-way-to-parse-command-line-arguments-in-c). I've personally used the  WPF TestAPI Library mentioned by [sixlettervariables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/491595/best-way-to-parse-command-line-arguments-in-c/491730#491730) and it is indeed pretty darn good