# Command Line Parsing

Tags: .net, asp.net, console

I need a command line parsing utility.  In the brief 10 second that I've spent googling, I found NConsoler.  Can anybody recommend anything else?

Comment: Please specify at least your operating system requirements, and which language you're working in.

Comment: Sorry, I should have tagged it .NET (althought NConsoler is for .NET console apps...)

Comment: In that case it is a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/631410/looking-for-a-command-line-argument-parser-for-net/1401547#1401547

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take a look at

http://commandline.codeplex.com/

and

[GetPot command line parser](http://getpot.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 4):

If you're interested in .NET (your question doesn't give any information) I've had the [Plossum.CommandLine](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/plossum_commandline.aspx?display=Print) library recommended to me before now. I haven't used it myself, but you might want to take a look.

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about .NET then see the answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/631410/looking-for-a-command-line-argument-parser-for-net/1401547#1401547) question.

Answer (score 1):

The [BizArk library](http://bizark.codeplex.com/) contains a command-line parser.

Basically you just create a class that inherits from CmdLineObject, add properties that you want populated from the command-line, add a CmdLineArgAttribute to the properties, then call Initialize in your program. It supports ClickOnce URL arguments too!

Features (from the site)...

- Automatic initialization: Class properties are automatically set based on the command-line arguments.
- Default properties: Send in a value without specifying the property name.
- Value conversion: Uses the powerful ConvertEx class also included in BizArk to convert values to the proper type.
- Boolean flags. Flags can be specified by simply using the argument (ex, /b for true and /b- for false) or by adding the value true/false, yes/no, etc.
- Argument arrays. Simply add multiple values after the command-line name to set a property that is defined as an array. Ex, /x 1 2 3 will populate x with the array { 1, 2, 3 } (assuming x is defined as an array of integers).
- Command-line aliases: A property can support multiple command-line aliases for it. For example, Help uses the alias ?.
- Partial name recognition. You don’t need to spell out the full name or alias, just spell enough for the parser to disambiguate the property/alias from the others.
- Supports ClickOnce: Can initialize properties even when they are specified as the query string in a URL for ClickOnce deployed applications. The command-line initialization method will detect if it is running as ClickOnce or not so your code doesn’t need to change when using it.
- Automatically creates /? help: This includes nice formatting that takes into account the width of the console.
- Load/Save command-line arguments to a file: This is especially useful if you have multiple large, complex sets of command-line arguments that you want to run multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Google's commandline-parsing library for C++ and python: http://code.google.com/p/google-gflags/