# How do you incorporate "/x" option parameters into a .NET console application?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, console-application

A lot of command line utilities use parameters, such as:

```
gacutil /i MyDLL.dll
```

or

```
regasm /tlb:MyDll.tlb MyDll.dll
```

How do I set up a .NET console application to take in command line arguments and, secondarily, how can you emulate handling "option" parameters like `/i` and `/tlb:` in the respective examples above?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to parse command line arguments in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/491595/best-way-to-parse-command-line-arguments-in-c)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You declare a parameter for the Main method:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
```

Now you have an array that for your first example contains:

```
args[0] = "/i"
args[1] = "MyDLL.dll"
```

You just have to parse the strings to determine what the parameter means. Something along the lines of:

```
foreach (string cmd in args) {
  if (cmd.StartsWith("/")) {
    switch (cmd.Substring(1)) {
      case "i":
        // handle /i parameter
        break;
      // some more options...
      default:
        // unknown parameter
        break;
    }
  } else {
    // cmd is the filename
  }
}
```

Comment: This ended up working for my simple solution, but I modified the switch statement a little (and is in VB.NET): `cmd.Substring(1, cmd.Length - 1).Split(New Char() {":"c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)(0).ToLower()`. That way I can use a full word as an option parameter.

Answer (score 5):

There is a good explanation at [Best way to parse command line arguments in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/491595/best-way-to-parse-command-line-arguments-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

You just make your `Main` method take a `string[]` parameter:

```
class Test
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        foreach (string arg in args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(arg);
        }
    }
}
```

It's up to you to parse the arguments appropriately, in that there's nothing built into the framework to do it. You might want to look at the [NDesk.Options](http://www.ndesk.org/Options) library though. (There are plenty of others, but that seems to be a popular one. I can't say I've used it myself, mind you.)

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle this by yourself (or use an existing library) to deal with command line parameters. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acy3edy3.aspx) (Main() and Command-Line Arguments).

One good library is [Mono.Options](http://www.ndesk.org/Options), another one I have used is [commandline](http://commandline.codeplex.com/).

In your console app, you will have a main method that takes a `string[]` parameter (by default and convention) this is named `args`. This array contains all the command line parameters. You can then parse these out.

Comment: +1 for commandline.  Very simple to use, available via NuGet, and a lot nicer than rolling your own code.

Answer (score 0):

[This page](http://averagecoder.net/passing-arguments-to-your-vbnet-console-application.htm) has a VB.NET example

```
Sub Main()
    Dim arrArgs() A s String = Command.Split(“,”)
    Dim i As Integer
    Console.Write(vbNewLine &amp; vbNewLine)
    If arrArgs(0) &lt;&gt; Nothing Then
        For i = LBound(arrArgs) To UBound(arrArgs)
            Console.Write(“Parameter “ &amp; i &amp; ” is “ &amp; arrArgs(i) &amp; vbNewLine)
        Next
    Else
        Console.Write(“No parameter passed”)
    End If
    Console.Write(vbNewLine &amp; vbNewLine)
End Sub
```

[This MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cb20e19t.aspx) has a C# example:

```
static int Main(string[] args)
{
    // Test if input arguments were supplied:
    if (args.Length == 0)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Please enter a numeric argument.");
        System.Console.WriteLine("Usage: Factorial <num>");
        return 1;
    }

    // Try to convert the input arguments to numbers. This will throw
    // an exception if the argument is not a number.
    // num = int.Parse(args[0]);
    int num;
    bool test = int.TryParse(args[0], out num);
    if (test == false)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Please enter a numeric argument.");
        System.Console.WriteLine("Usage: Factorial <num>");
        return 1;
    }
.....
```

Answer (score 0):

The entry point of the application can be declared as:

```
static void Main (string[] args) { ... }
```

This gives you an array of strings in which each element is one of the command line parameters.  Once you've got that it's just a matter of parsing the strings in the array to configure the options in your app.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to write my own logic for this, since I usually don't want to create an additional external dependency for my console application.

Below is some code that I wrote to populate some variables using the command line arguments.  This code is intended to support prefixing parameter names with either "/" or "-" and, if the parameter takes a value (i.e. it's not a flag), supports separating the value from the name by either ":" or " ".

Please excuse the lack of comments ;)

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string directory = null;
        string filePattern = null;
        string sourceDirectory = null;
        string targetDirectory = null;
        List<string> version = null;
        string action = null;
        bool showHelp = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
        {
            string parameterName;
            int colonIndex = args[i].IndexOf(':');
            if (colonIndex >= 0)
                parameterName = args[i].Substring(0, colonIndex);
            else
                parameterName = args[i];
            switch (parameterName.ToLower())
            {
                case "-dir":
                case "/dir":
                    if (colonIndex >= 0)
                    {
                        int valueStartIndex = colonIndex + 1;
                        directory = args[i].Substring(valueStartIndex, args[i].Length - valueStartIndex);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        i++;
                        if (i < args.Length)
                        {
                            directory = args[i];
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            System.Console.WriteLine("Expected a directory to be specified with the dir parameter.");
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case "-sourcedir":
                case "/sourcedir":
                    if (colonIndex >= 0)
                    {
                        int valueStartIndex = colonIndex + 1;
                        sourceDirectory = args[i].Substring(valueStartIndex, args[i].Length - valueStartIndex);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        i++;
                        if (i < args.Length)
                        {
                            sourceDirectory = args[i];
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            System.Console.WriteLine("Expected a directory to be specified with the sourcedir parameter.");
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case "-targetdir":
                case "/targetdir":
                    if (colonIndex >= 0)
                    {
                        int valueStartIndex = colonIndex + 1;
                        targetDirectory = args[i].Substring(valueStartIndex, args[i].Length - valueStartIndex);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        i++;
                        if (i < args.Length)
                        {
                            targetDirectory = args[i];
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            System.Console.WriteLine("Expected a directory to be specified with the targetdir parameter.");
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case "-file":
                case "/file":
                    if (colonIndex >= 0)
                    {
                        int valueStartIndex = colonIndex + 1;
                        filePattern = args[i].Substring(valueStartIndex, args[i].Length - valueStartIndex);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        i++;
                        if (i < args.Length)
                        {
                            filePattern = args[i];
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            System.Console.WriteLine("Expected a file pattern to be specified with the file parameter.");
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case "-action":
                case "/action":
                    if (colonIndex >= 0)
                    {
                        int valueStartIndex = colonIndex + 1;
                        action = args[i].Substring(valueStartIndex, args[i].Length - valueStartIndex);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        i++;
                        if (i < args.Length)
                        {
                            action = args[i];
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            System.Console.WriteLine("Expected an action to be specified with the action parameter.");
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case "-version":
                case "/version":
                    if (version == null)
                        version = new List<string>();
                    if (colonIndex >= 0)
                    {
                        int valueStartIndex = colonIndex + 1;
                        version.Add(args[i].Substring(valueStartIndex, args[i].Length - valueStartIndex));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        i++;
                        if (i < args.Length)
                        {
                            version.Add(args[i]);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            System.Console.WriteLine("Expected a version to be specified with the version parameter.");
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case "-?":
                case "/?":
                case "-help":
                case "/help":
                    showHelp = true;
                    break;
                default:
                    System.Console.WriteLine("Unrecognized parameter \"{0}\".", parameterName);
                    return;
            }
        }

        // At this point, all of the command line arguments have been read
        // and used to populate the variables that I defined at the top.
        // The rest of my application will work with the variables
        // and will not reference to args array again.
    }
```