# How do I use command line arguments in my C# console app?

Tags: c#, console, console-application

I am writing a url shortener app and I would like to also create a console app with C# to push the URLs to a WCF service which I have also created.

WCF app will shorten the url on this URI;

http://example.com/shorten/http://exaple.com

so what I want is just that.

My console exe file will be sitting inside `c:\dev` folder and on Windows command line, I would like to do this;

> c:\dev>myapp -throw http://example.com

with this method I would like to talk to that service. there is no problem on talking part. But the problem is how can I supply this ***-throw*** thing on the command line and get a response and put that response on the command line and supply a method to copy that to the clipboard. Am I asking too much here? :S I don't know.

Could you direct me somewhere that I can find information on that or could u please give me an example code of this?

Thanks.

**EDIT :** 
I have tried the following code;

```
    class Program {

    static void Main(string[] args) {

        if (args[0] == "-throw") {

            System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.SetDataObject(args[1]);
            Console.WriteLine(args[1] + " has been added to clipboard !");
            Console.ReadLine();

        }

    }
}
```

and I received the following error;

> C:\Apps\ArgsTry\ArgsTry\bin\Debug>ArgsTry
>   -throw man
>
> Unhandled Exception:
>   System.Threading.ThreadStateException:
>   Current thread must be set to single
>   thread apartment (STA) mode before OLE
>   calls can be made. Ensur e that your
>   Main function has STAThreadAttribute
>   marked on it.    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.SetDataObject(Object
>   data, Boolean copy, In t32 retryTimes,
>   Int32 retryDelay)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.SetDataObject(Object
>   data)    at
>   ArgsTry.Program.Main(String[] args) in
>   c:\apps\ArgsTry\ArgsTry\Program.cs:
>   line 14
>
> C:\Apps\ArgsTry\ArgsTry\bin\Debug>

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to parse command line arguments in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/491595/best-way-to-parse-command-line-arguments-in-c)

Comment: Have you looked into/open to using a framework to handle command line arguments for you?  I'm a fan of CommandLineParser: [link](https://commandline.codeplex.com/).  It really does make dealing with incoming command line args a lot easier.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Passing arguments to a console application is easy:

```
using System;

public class CommandLine
{
   public static void Main(string[] args)
   {
       for(int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
       {
           if( args[i] == "-throw" )
           {
               // call http client args[i+1] for URL
           }
       }
   }
}
```

As for the clipboard, see:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.clipboard.aspx

Comment: thanks for your reply. I have updated my qu as above. tried the clipboard thing but received an error.

Answer (score 1):

See the args below, you can use it to read all the values passed when you run your exe file.

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
```

Comment: args[0] will like "-throw" and args[1] will be the url and args[n...] will be the succeeding values.

Comment: ok. after that, how can I view the response on the command line? with writeline() ?

Comment: Console.Writeline() is your friend for that. :)