# Implement command that added in shortcut target

Tags: c#, command, arguments, shortcut

I'm making this small program that depends in shortcut command, for example:

```
"D:\Games\Counter Strike 1.6\hl.exe" -game cstrike
```

in shortcut target "-game cstrike" was added, hl.exe will not run the same as if that command wasn't there. so how would i make special commands like that? i couldn't explain the problem in short words that's why i couldn't google it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short words that you can google it **"Console Application Command Argument."**

I hope help this link:

[How do I use command line arguments in my C# console app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5700631/how-do-i-use-command-line-arguments-in-my-c-sharp-console-app#)