# Use parameters from PowerShell to C#

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, parameters

I would like to execute an application (C# .NET core) by a little PowerShell script. However I would like during the execution of this application to send one parameter present in the PowerShell script.

How can I execute that ?

Thanks you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can send the parameter as an argument to the exe directly and you can read that in the main method easily. Some thing like this:

C:\Foo.exe "test"

Comment: Let me know if you are facing any issues with this approach.

Comment: Hello, I am very sorry for the delay. However I can not get the parameter in C #.
You know how can I gete a parameter on C# ? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Inside the Main method you need to add arguments property using that you can get the parameters. Take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5700631/how-do-i-use-command-line-arguments-in-my-c-sharp-console-app