# Best practice to handle command line arguments in C#

Tags: console-application, command-line-arguments, c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to parse command line arguments in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/491595/best-way-to-parse-command-line-arguments-in-c)

What's the best practice for handling command line arguments?

That is, I want my console application (VC#2008) to be able to handle arguments on command line just like most of the other command line tools do:

```
> mytool.exe -LongArgument Value -sa value --abcdef
```

Where the arguments are `LongArgument: Value`, `sa` is an abbr. of `ShortArgument` with `value` and `abcdef` are switch-arguments that are just activated when given.

How can I code this in a way that is easily extensible when new arguments come along?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use the .net port of the apache commons cli API. This works great.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/dotnetcli/

and the original API for concepts and introduction

http://commons.apache.org/cli/

Comment: How does this differ from the one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/491595/best-way-to-parse-command-line-arguments-in-c this one? It also seems quite advanced.

Comment: Please stop pasting the exact same answer on multiple questions, even when the answer pertains.