# Manage my application properties run

Tags: c#, parameters, properties, arguments

I have application - a runner that runs the same logic over and over with different parameters every time.

I'm looking for a mechanism/code that already implemented properties mechanism that contains the parameter name, parameter type, parameter value and stuff like that.

I remember that I saw this in the past but I can't find it on the web (and even had lots of other advantages).

does someone know such implementation that is available?

Comment: Your question is hard to understand. Could you post an example of what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand your question, but I believe you mean a command line parsing library.

There are many such libraries - here is [one](http://www.ndesk.org/Options).

See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/491595/best-way-to-parse-command-line-arguments-in-c) about this subject - there are recommendations in the answers.