# read command line switch

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to read user arguments in a C# application. I know how to read them based on position with

```
string[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
```

but I'd like to read them from switches such as

```
app.exe /f /d:foo
```

I'm really struggling to find any information on doing this...

Comment: Unfortunately, C# doesn't give you much more information than simply a list of command-line arguments as strings. It doesn't even include the .exe name.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Why don't you just parse the array of arguments passed and act based on them, like this

```
foreach (string arg in args)
{
    switch (arg.Substring(0, 2).ToUpper())
    {
        case "/F":
            // process argument...
            break;
        case "/Z":
            // process arg...
            break;
        case "/D":
            paramD = arg.Substring(3);
            break;
        default:
            // do other stuff...
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I've seen a couple of answers that loop through the args string collection - the problem is you need the next item after you hit the switch you are looking for.  I used the array index of the collection in order to get the next item.

In my sample I'm looking for a server and a port /S and /P.  I hope this helps someone:

```
        var server = string.Empty;
        var port = string.Empty;

        for(var x = 0; x < args.Count(); x++)
        {
            switch (args[x].Trim().ToUpper())
            {
                case "/S":
                    server = args[x + 1];
                    break;
                case "/P":
                    port = args[x + 1];
                    break;                                        
            }
        }
```

Comment: You'll probably want to advance x after setting the value to the next argument. Otherwise, you'll needlessly process that arg:
server = args[++x];

Comment: ... but the mentioned `/d:foo` use case isn't caught by your solution

Answer (score 4):

```
void Main(string[] args )
{
    foreach( var arg in args )
    {
        // process each arg if needed, i.e., 
        // remove '-', '/', uppercase, whatever
        switch(arg)
        {
            case "blah":
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Libraries do exist for this purpose which make the whole process a lot easier, but if this is a one off app it may not be worth it.  Depends on how complex your command line arguments are.

Comment: @MTeck - [Mono.Options](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/Mono.Options/Mono.Options/Options.cs) is a great lightweight example of such a library.

Answer (score 3):

What about,

```
// first is exe of executing program
string[] args = Environment.CommandLine.Split('/').Skip(1).ToArray();
foreach (string arg in args)
{
    string value = arg.Trim();
    switch (value)
    {
        case "f":
            //...
            continue;
    }
    if (value.StartsWith("d:"))
    {
        value = value.Substring(2);
        // ...
        continue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, basically you already done.
Process that `string[]` array you get from the framework and you done. 
There is no built-in way to achieve what you're asking for.

Like 3rd parties solution can have a look on

[C#/.NET Command Line Arguments Parser](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3111/C-NET-Command-Line-Arguments-Parser)

Answer (score 0):

I am the author of an open source .NET command-line library that may suit your needs: [C# CLI](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ccli).

You may also want to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/491595/best-way-to-parse-command-line-arguments-in-c) question for other suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you'll have to roll your own implementation. After writing unit tests to evaluate the new method, I might start thinking along the lines of ...

```
foreach (string arg in args)
{
    flagF = flagF || arg == "/f"; // assuming F is boolean
    flagD = flagD ?? (arg.Substring(0,3) =="/d:" ? arg.Substring(3) : null);
}
```

Comment: flagF should be initialized to false, then do `flagF |= arg == "/f";` so that once it becomes true, it stays true.  The way you have it now, flagF is always true.

Comment: then for flagD, in your `()` change the 2 to 3 as `"/d:"` is 3 characters.

Comment: @ChuckSavage thanks; the code got the idea across anyway, even if hastily written :-). Correcting now.

Answer (score 0):

Some packages that might be of interest:

1. `Microsoft.Extensions.CommandLineUtils` package:
   https://www.areilly.com/2017/04/21/command-line-argument-parsing-in-net-core-with-microsoft-extensions-commandlineutils/
2. `System.CommandLine` package (prerelease at the time of writing):
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2019/march/net-parse-the-command-line-with-system-commandline