# C# Using Multiple Arguments

Tags: c#, command-line-arguments

This is from a newer C# guy,

I have been back and forth through different questions posed on here but I haven't found anything that answers directly to what I need to know.

I have a console application that I want to pass arguments to, through the command line. This is what I have so far and it's working for a single argument, now I got to add another but I can't seem to figure out where to start.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    if (args == null || args.Length== 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("that's not it");
        help();
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
        {
            backupfolder = args[i];
        }
        checks();
    }
}
```

If I take everything out of my else statement how can I set what the args are and assign? Will the below work ?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    if (args == null || args.Length== 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("that's not it");
        help();
    }
    else
    {
        string backupfolder = args[0];
        string filetype = args[1];
        checks();
    }
}
```

Comment: `args[1];` this may not work with your current code

Comment: you need to add null check for second argument, cuz its possible that second argument is not sent and is null

Comment: Pass arguments by separated by white space

Comment: Well, you can't be sure if you actually received 2 arguments unless you check it first, right? If you don't have 2nd argument, i.e args[1], you will get an exception. *Edit: And that's a pretty good formatted question for a  "newer C# guy", you have my upvote :)

Comment: Start with `args.Length != 2` *(in the first check)* when there should be always two arguments, or `args.Length >= 2` when there should be at least two arguments.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [read command line switch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9742924/1260204)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to parse command line arguments in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/491595/1260204)

Comment: Consider using https://www.nuget.org/packages/commandlineparser/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to check the length of the `args` array before attempting to retrieve values from it:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // There must be at least 2 command line arguments...
    if (args == null || args.Length < 2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("that's not it");
        help();
    }
    else 
    {
        string backupfolder = args[0]; 
        string filetype = args[1];
        checks();
    }
}
```

Another option, if you want to allow passing only some of the expected arguments:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // There must be at least 1 command line arguments.
    if (args == null || args.Length < 1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("that's not it");
        help();
    }
    else 
    {
        // You already know there is at least one argument here...
        string backupfolder = args[0]; 
        // Check if there is a second argument, 
        // provide a default value if it's missing
        string filetype = (args.Length > 1) ? args[1] : "" ;
        checks();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, the second option was going to be my next question, so you hit it on the mark. 

Thanks, everyone.

Comment: Although most hobby programmers feel a bit like cheating by using libraries, in this case I can really recommend the Command Line Parser package on NuGet: https://www.nuget.org/packages/commandlineparser. It allows you to have *NIX-like command lines: `--backup myfolder -t filetype --file file1 --file file2 -f file3` and have them automatically parsed into a class.