# How to pass commands to already running command prompt in C#?

Tags: c#

Suppose I opened command prompt in my system and now I want to pass a command through c# program  to that open command prompt window  only and i dont want to open new instance of command prompt window to execute the command which I am passing through C# program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using FindWindow API and SendKeys.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you mean "open new instance" to execute arguments which you passed already. However, if you are not quite sure how to parse intensively command line arguments you can take a reference of this link :

[Best way to parse command line arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/491595/best-way-to-parse-command-line-arguments-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

You need to send keys to an open application. The belolw link will help you

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18366/Sending-Keystrokes-to-another-Application-in-C

Comment: Thanks, now i got the answer from the above link