# C# separating args parameters

Tags: c#, arrays, cmd

I have a program that calculates the factorial of multiple numbers. These nubers are passed as parameters in cmd as such :

```
factorial.exe 3 4 5
```

This will calculate the factorials of 3, 4 and 5 respectively.
An earlier version of the program had a percentage that showed the fullness of the stack. I want to bring that back now, but I to also pass the wait time as a parameter in cmd as such:

```
factorial.exe 3 4 5 wait_time1
```

or

```
factorial.exe 3 4 5 1000
```

To read the numbers I use this args parser :

```
static string the_time;
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        foreach (string s in args)
        {

            extra = int.Parse(s);

            Calculate(extra);
        }
     }
```

How can I separate the arguments?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add the `waittime` arg like a switch `/t:100` so only when you see `/t` you know it is a `waittime`.

If you know your args will always have the `waittime`, then `waittime` is

```
waittime = arg[args.Length-1]
```

Probably worth a look as well

- [Best way to parse command line arguments in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/491595/best-way-to-parse-command-line-arguments-in-c)

In case you don't want to reinvent the wheel

- http://commandline.codeplex.com/
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3852/Automatic-Command-Line-Parsing-in-C

Comment: And here we have a complete answer =) +1

Answer (score 1):

I think, what you want is something like getopt on UNIX-like machines to parse arguments in a sensible way. Have a look [here](http://getopt.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Each element at the array will be a string from the command line, space-divided. This way, for

```
factorial.exe 3 4 5
```

will you have

```
args[0] //3
args[1] //4
args[2] //5
```

**EDIT**

Thanks to DD59, now I understand your question. You could have a convention that the last parameter will always be the wait time, or you could use a syntax, such as `-time` (or `/t:`, as he said).

```
factorial.exe 3 4 5 -1000
```

Regards

Comment: I think the OPs question is how does he differ between the number arguments and the wait time.

Comment: @Hinek Inded, I've edited the answer now that I see it clearly.

Answer (score 0):

You are already separating the arguments in foreach loop. The string s is what you get as argument. I suppose you want to pinpoint the wait_time value and don't want to calculate it of course. You have to fix the position like - last argument is wait_time or first arugment is. Without fixing the location it will be hard to determine.

Answer (score 0):

Is wait_time a mandatory argument? Does it always stand at the last place? Then you could do it like this:

```
the_time = args[args.Length - 1];
for (int i=0; i<args.length - 1; i++){ 
    extra = int.Parse(args[i]); 
    Calculate(extra); 
}
```

If wait_time is optional, you should go with DD59's answer.

Comment: it is mandatory and for some reason this doesn't work... If I place the time as the first parameter it works faster than it should if it's last it works slower... need to take a look at this

Comment: The code above checks for you wait_time in the last argument. So putting it first will result in the last of your numbers being interpreted as the wait_time ...

Answer (score 0):

Parsing the command line is a quite complex part. Maybe you should take a look at a available library (some examples):

- http://commandline.codeplex.com/
- https://github.com/mono/mono/tree/master/mcs/class/Mono.Options/