# Adding custom variables to the end of application path when executed in c#

Tags: c#, .net, arguments

How would I read custom variables end of my application path?  I am not sure exactly what they are called, but for example in in the shortcut path of Google Chrome you can add settings to the end of the path such as:

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe **--Custom-setting**"

How would I read these arguments after my application has started?

Comment: Are you using Winforms or a Console App?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/491595/best-way-to-parse-command-line-arguments-in-c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are arguments that you are passing to the application.  For example take the following application:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
if (args == null)
{
    Console.WriteLine("args is null"); // Check for null array
}
else
{
    Console.Write("args length is ");
    Console.WriteLine(args.Length); // Write array length
    for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++) // Loop through array
    {
    string argument = args[i];
    Console.Write("args index ");
    Console.Write(i); // Write index
    Console.Write(" is [");
    Console.Write(argument); // Write string
    Console.WriteLine("]");
    }
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

If you ran the following from the command line:

```
"C:\ConsoleApplication1.exe" a b c
```

The program would display:

```
args length is 3
args index 0 is [a]
args index 1 is [b]
args index 2 is [c]
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acy3edy3.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cb20e19t.aspx

Answer (score 2):

These values will be contained in the args array in the `Main()` method which serves as the entry point of your application.

```
static void Main(string[] args) { }
```

- [Command-Line Arguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cb20e19t%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [Main() and Command-Line Arguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acy3edy3.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

They are called command line arguments. Although you can parse them [manually](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288457%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) directly from your `main()` program entry point, there are several helper libraries which can make life even easier for you and your users, such as this one [here](http://nuget.org/packages/CommandLineParser) and [here](http://commandline.codeplex.com/).