# command parser/interpreter

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to parse command line arguments in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/491595/best-way-to-parse-command-line-arguments-in-c)

I'm looking for a library that can provide easy command parsing.  Somthing similar to command line parsers would be fine.  The trouble with a command line parser is getting the actual command and paring it to the options easily.

For instance I may want to turn on debugging. To do so I would want to do something like this.

```
debug on -f "c:\logs\debug file.txt"
```

If I wanted to turn on optimization I could do this.

```
optimize on
```

or

```
optimize off
```

While I might be able to get a standard command line parser to accomplish this, there would need to be a bit of preprocessing before actually using a standard command line parser.  I'm really just looking for an elegant solution that won't require tons of debugging.

On a side note, has anyone any recommendation using python in .NET?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python has one built in called argparse [Python argparser](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#module-argparse)

And for C# you can use: [C# Argparse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/491595/best-way-to-parse-command-line-arguments-in-c)

If I needed to write one myself, I'd start out by writing a stack-based language interpreter, and then it'll be really easy to parse options. You'll have written half the grammar just by writing the lexer.

Python is one of those things that when you add it to anything, it instantly becomes awesome. So you can only imagine what using Python with .NET would be like. Coming from personal experience, you can do a lot of work very quickly using IronPython. (Oh, and you can use the TPL (Task Parallelism Library) too.

Have fun!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  I've looked at the stackoverflow question you referenced and it pointed me to a few decent command line parsers.  however, I'm not sure they can do just what I need.  I've thought about creating my own interpreter, however, as I've never done such a thing, I feel it would be a large undertaking.  Perhaps in the future.  I'll check out IronPython, as I do really like Python.

Comment: It's easy peasy in Python, check out this link: http://4.flowsnake.org/archives/252

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the reference.  That is quite interesting, I think i may do some projects on the side to expand on that proof of concept.  I think it could come in great handy.