# Regular Expressions, an example for beginner

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to figure out a quite simple regular expression, but I cannot reconstruct, why it does not work. I thought I'm into the regex stuff, but unfortunately it doesn't seem so :D

Here is the expression I want to match:

`interval=4|termination=2012-09-18 22:00:00|days=3`

By that, I want to have a matching array that looks anyhow like this

```
match = array({"interval" => "4", "termination" => "2012-09-18 22:00:00", "days" = "3"});
//(pseudocode)
```

I'm using it in C#, for that I want to have pattern names. I tried it with this pattern:

```
(.*)((termination=(?<termination>(.{19})))|(interval=(?<interval>(\d*)))|(days=(?<days>(\d*))))*(.*)
```

Can anybody point out where I fail?

Thx in advance

Comment: Have you tested it using a regex tool? Many tools decompose your resulting matches (or missing matches) which can help. I use the free RAD Regex Designer (http://www.radsoftware.com.au/regexdesigner/), but there are others.

Comment: I can recommend regex101.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are coming from PHP background, you can use `string.Split` and a force the output to a dictionary like:

```
string str = "interval=4|termination=2012-09-18 22:00:00|days=3";
Dictionary<string,string> dict = str.Split('|')
                                    .Select(r => r.Split('='))
                                    .ToDictionary(t => t[0], t=> t[1]);
```

and the output would be:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for that answer, that is certainly one way to do it in this case, but I'm seeking a regex approach to build up more sophisticated usages.

Answer (score 1):

`|` is special character for regex, which means alternation. Since you want to match literal `|`, you need to escape it.

```
interval=(?<interval>\d*)\|termination=(?<termination>.{19})\|days=(?<days>\d*)
```

I have also take the liberty to clean up the capturing groups that you don't seem to need. I have also modified the regex, so that it works with [`Regex.Matches()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches.aspx) method.

I assume that the input appears in the order specified.

Comment: To OP: I am not sure what you are trying when you use `|` in your regex. If the input comes in the same order as shown, then the regex I wrote will work. Otherwise, it needs more modification.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for that suggestion. Yeah, I want to be insensitive to the order.

Answer (score 1):

What are the results you're getting? I'm betting that `(.*)`, being greedy, will consume the whole string, while the other parts (suffixed by `*`) will be matched zero times. So the match will succeed, but the capturing groups will be empty. Is that what you're experiencing?

My suggestion would be to go with `Split` as suggested by Habib, but if you want to fix your regex then:

- Make the first group [non-greedy (lazy)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html): `(.*?)`
- Fix the order of your fields, and escape `|` as suggested by nhahtdh, or:
- If the fields can come out of order, you might need to repeat them to accept zero, one or more (not the best job for a regex, but doable):

  ```
  (
      (termination=(...)|interval=(...)|days=(...))
      (\| (termination=(...)|interval=(...)|days=(...)) )*
  )?
  ```

  (spaces and newlines added for readability)

Comment: That is exactly what I'm experiencing. Tons of empty arrays, I guess there is some error in my thinking. Another example I want to get working is the processing of program parameters at the invocation of my cli-program (e.g. start.exe /help /param1 5 /param2 "hello")

Comment: @GiehlMan While it's nice to have a good grasp of regexes, I tend to only use them when simpler alternatives aren't in place. For parsing command-line arguments, the preferred approach AFAIK is using [`OptionSet`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/491595/520779). But if what you want is to learn, check my comments and link above about greedy vs. lazy quantifiers, and you might also be interested in [non capturing groups](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3512471/520779) (to make your results cleaner). Using `^` and `$` to force a full string match is also helpful.