# How to write a program in C# that can take arguments

Tags: c#, .net, arguments

I've seen alot of command-line programs that take arguments, like *ping google.com -t*. How can I make a program like ping? I would like my program to take a number as an argument and then further use this number:
    For example:
`geturi -n 1188`

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/491595/best-way-to-parse-command-line-arguments-in-c). Welcome to Stackoverflow. Unfortunately, this is not a [real question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145677/what-is-a-real-question) for here. Did you try anything so far? Please show your efforts first so that other people might help you out. Also, please read [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: I've searched on google but really found nothing on my own because I'm not entirely sure what keywords to search for I assume.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a normal Console Application, in `static void Main(string[] args)`, simply use the `args`. If you want to read the first argument as a number, then you simply use:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    if (args.Length > 1)
    {
        int arg;
        if (int.TryParse(args[0], out arg))
            // use arg
        else // show an error message (the input was not a number)
    }
    else // show an error message (there was no input)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just write a generic, console application.

[image]

The main method looks like the following snippet:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
    }
}
```

Your arguments are included in the `args` array.

Comment: Please up-vote and accept the answer if this was what you were looking for.  Also, try to describe your situation a bit further in your question and, also, double-check that this question hasn't been asked.  StackOverflow is a reasonably nice place, however, duplicates and poor questions are not tolerated.