# Capture file I right clicked on

Tags: c#

I have an idea I want to make. Basically it's a tiny program that moves a file to a specific folder, the idea came about because I'm sorting through pictures taken on the phone and the screen shots I take on my phone has to be moved to another folder.

As for the implementation, I was thinking of adding a context menu item when you right click a file. When you click on that menu item the file gets moved to a specific folder.

My problem is, I don't know where to start looking for inspiration. I found something that sounds a bit like it, but isn't:[Global Windows Hooks](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19858/Global-Windows-Hooks)

I found a way to add my own menu items to the right click menu, I can start a program that way. But how do I capture the file I right clicked on? Using string[] args in some way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write a program in C# that can take arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17456482/how-to-write-a-program-in-c-sharp-that-can-take-arguments)

Comment: This may also help https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/add-any-application-to-the-desktop-right-click-menu-in-vista/