# How to get only odd arguments

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to get only odd arguments in a list. Here is a piece of my code

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
     var swictches = args.ToList().Select((x, index) => (index % 2) == 1);
     var ss = swictches[0];

     string test = doc.ReadAllPages();
     Console.WriteLine(test.Substring(0, 1000));
     Console.Read();
}
```

In the arguments list it has switches and parameters. I am trying to get all the switches. When I run this code the switches variable looks like this:

```
false
true
false
```

instead of like this

```
-i
-awq
-l
```

Comment: You want `Where` instead of `Select`.

Comment: that's because you're selecting `index % 2`

Comment: Does your code compile? `IEnumerable<string>[0]` ??

Comment: And if you just need the first item use `First`, rather than calling `ToList` on the query just to get the first item.

Comment: The better idea: use a [commandline-switches library](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2067916).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `Where` instead of `Select`:

```
var swictches = args.Where((x, index) => (index % 2) == 1).ToList();
```

- [`Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.where.aspx) filters items based on specified predicate.
- [`Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.select.aspx) projects elements from one format into another (from `string` to `bool` in your code).

Also, you don't have to call `ToList()` to use `Where`/`Select`. `string[]` implements `IEnumerable<string>` as well, so you can just use LINQ on it. Instead of calling `ToList` at the beginning call it as the last method, to instantiate results into `List<string>`.

**Edit:**

As pointed in comments. You should use `First` when you need just the first element from sequence, instead of calling `ToList()` and using `[0]` on the results. It's will be faster:

```
var ss = args.Where((x, index) => (index % 2) == 1).First();
```

Answer (score 2):

var switchesFixed = args.Where((item, index) => index % 2 != 0);   //returns Even args

var switchesFixed = args.Where((item, index) => index % 2 == 0);   //returns Odd args

Answer (score 1):

Another variant to find all switches:
`args.Where(s => s.StartsWith("-")).ToList()`