# How to get the solution path in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, path

I need to get the path where the solution file (.sln) is located. I try with this lines:

```
string startupPath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetParent(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).Parent.Parent.Parent.FullName,"abc.txt");

// Read the file as one string. 
string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(startupPath);
```

When I run it, I get an "Unauthorized Access Exception". When I put the path "manually": `C:\Users\yabej\source\repos\tutoriales\Proyecto 0.1` it works!

However I need an "automatic" solution to be sure that the path will be correct when I run my project on different computers

Comment: The solution file (.sln) will not be on the production computer. You cannot have a general purpose solution for this.

Comment: Why would the code in a project need to know the path to the solution folder? I suspect that you're trying to solve the wrong problem. Please explain what you're actually trying to achieve rather than how you're trying to achieve it.

Comment: @jmcilhinney i'm trying to execute a .exe from my project using a button. The folder with the .exe is in the solution folder. Thats why i need the path.

Comment: That doesn't really make sense. Once you deploy your application to another machine, the solution folder and the project folder no longer exist as far as the application is concerned. If your application was installed in a user's 'Program Files' folder, where's the solution folder? If your application wants to access files then they should either be under the program folder, which you can get using `Application.StartupPath`, or a standard location, which you can get using `Environment.GetFolderPath`.

Answer (score 2):

The **proper** way to get the right solution path worked for me in Visual Studio 2019 with the EnvDTE100 NuGet Package.

*Clarification: Only works with a single VS Instance Open (credits @junliantolovich)*

Be sure use the correct **ProgId** for your *Visual Studio*:

```
using System;
using EnvDTE80;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Test
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            var di = GetSolutionDirInfo();
            Console.WriteLine(di.FullName);
        }

        public static DirectoryInfo GetSolutionDirInfo()
        {
            // Use here the ProgId of your Visual Studio
            // VS 2010 ->  "VisualStudio.DTE.10.0"
            // VS 2012 ->  "VisualStudio.DTE.11.0"
            // VS 2013 ->  "VisualStudio.DTE.12.0"
            // VS 2015 ->  "VisualStudio.DTE.14.0"
            // VS 2017 ->  "VisualStudio.DTE.15.0"
            // VS 2019 ->  "VisualStudio.DTE.16.0"
            var progId = "VisualStudio.DTE.16.0";
            var dte2 = (DTE2)Marshal.GetActiveObject(progId);
            return Directory.GetParent(dte2.Solution.FullName);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Be aware, I had a couple solutions open, and run into an issue that this actually get another solution's path instead of the one running this code.

Comment: @junliantolovich you are right, with 2 solutions opened it didn't work, just works with a single VS instance open.

Answer (score -1):

If you add your file (abc.txt) to your solution, then in the properties for the file, you can set 'Copy to output directory' to 'Copy always'. Make sure the build action is set to 'None'. Then during the build process, it'll be copied to the same location as your executable and you can get the path using

```
var path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "\\abc.txt");
```

Comment: That would apply to a file in a project but, while I've never tested it, I don't think it would apply to a file in the solution. Given that a solution can contain multiple projects, which output folder would it get copied to?

Comment: Also, `GetCurrentDirectopry` is the wrong option. It should be `Application.StartupPath`, assuming a WinForms application. The current directory for the process will generally be the program folder by default but it won't necessarily be and, even if it is, there are things that can change the current directory during a session.

Comment: There's also no point explicitly prefixing the file name with a delimiter. One of the major reasons to use `Path.Combine` is that it will ensure that one delimiter is used between partial paths regardless of whether either, neither or both include them.