# Regex validation for custom command format

Tags: c#, regex, validation

I need to validate some commands with the format similar to this

```
"/a foo.bar /b bar.foo /c 01(.01)"
```

where the final (.01) is optional (brackets are there to mark the contents as optional). Any digits can be set instead of the 0's and 1's. Also the switches /a, /b, /c are fixed
For the moment, I've developed this regular expression:

```
@"/a\s*([\w\W]*)\s*/b\s*([\w\W]*)\s*/c\s*[0-9,0-9,(.,0-9,0-9){0,1}]
```

but for some reason, if the command is for example

```
"/a foo.bar /b bar.foo /c 01.",
```

it still validates against the regex. Valid commands should end either with 2digits.2digits or simple 2digits.

Can someone help me to get this fixed?

Cheers,

Alex Barac

Comment: Isn't it easier to parse the command line (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/491595/best-way-to-parse-command-line-arguments-in-c), letting the library take care of parsing and checking the types? Then you only have to check the result for options a, b and c being set.

Comment: Good suggestion, but I'm in a sort of time crysis and I need this fixed kind of asap...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
^/a\s*(.*)\s*/b\s*(.*)\s*/c\s*((\d{2}\.\d{2})|(\d{2}))$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/Gm5PFOpO3mZdqYyo)

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I wanted! I wish I could up your answer twice for the link to the visual regex tester.

Comment: Nice regular expression representation. +1

Comment: `a*? Zero or more a's (lazy)`, actually, it's not needed, I removed it.

Answer (score 0):

You're misunderstanding *character classes*. For example, this:

```
[0-9,0-9,(.,0-9,0-9){0,1}]
```

and this:

```
[0-9,.(){}]
```

mean the same thing. In other words, no matter what you put within the square brackets, that expression matches a *single* character, unless you *quantify* the character class. What you want, instead, is this:

```
@"/a\s*([\w\W]*)\s*/b\s*([\w\W]*)\s*/c\s*[0-9][0-9](\(\.[0-9][0-9])){0,1}"
```

But let me help you simplify and fix this further:

1. You can probably use `.` (a wildcard) rather than `[\w\W]` (unless you're doing that specifically to match newline characters as well—by default, `.` doesn't match newlines).
2. That's why I escaped the `.` that you actually mean to mean a dot, near the end.
3. Parentheses are also special characters, which is why I've escaped them, near the end.
4. `\d` is shorthand for `[0-9]`.
5. The outer parentheses are so you can apply the `{0,1}` *quantifier* on a *group*.
6. `?` is shorthand for `{0,1}`.

Taking all that into account:

```
@"/a\s*(.*)\s*/b\s*(.*)\s*/c\s*\d\d(\(\.\d\d))?"
```

Last two things. First, if there should be at least *one* space between arguments, you should use `\s+` instead of `\s*`. Second, if you want to allow more than two digits, then you can do `\d+` instead of `\d\d`.

Comment: Well, that's the part i'm having problems with. How should I correctly quantify an expression of type .digitdigit to appear once or not at all?

Comment: This should help in my future regex development. Thanks!