# What's the proper way to deal with \ in .NET console application arguments?

Tags: c#, .net, cmd

I wrote a small application to copy files from source to destination. I expected two parameters, source and destination. The following command works fine.

```
test.exe "C:\source path" "D:\destination"
```

The problem I have is when I pass the parameter within `"` and end it with `\` then it messes up.

For example:

```
test.exe "C:\source path\" "D:\destination"
```

Since `\` is an escape character then test.exe gets the first argument as `C:\source path"` instead of `C:\source path\`

So, what's the proper way to deal with this problem.

Even the most basic sample shows that strange behavior - `\"` passed from command line get converted into `"`:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
 foreach(var s in args)
 {
    System.Console.WriteLine(s);
 }
}
```

Comment: `\ ` is not "escape character" for CMD, `^` is...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov thanks for comment, I have updated the title to make it clearer.

Comment: Turned out somewhat "well known" behavior :(. http://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+command+line+quotes

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I read the link you marked as duplicate before I posted this question but there is no answer there, just explanation. My intention is to find the solution or work-around for this problem, not the reason why it works this way.

Comment: You could have linked it in the beginning (and phrase your question more like you comment) to save some confusion in answers... But I'm afraid it would be off-topic as there really 2 options - find parser you like (off-topic as searching for links) or write your own (need code in the post, I'd probably search for existing instead).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov It's possible to write a parser to solved this problem or finding an existing one but this is such a common problem and I think it might have a best practice or a proper way to deal it. There are many console apps out there that deal with `\` properly and I am pretty sure that that is a way to do this nicely. Again, the point is this question is not duplicate with the one above. There is no answer on that one.

Comment: You probably should edit your question so it is clear what you are looking for and why it would not be duplicate of something like "related" - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/491595/best-way-to-parse-command-line-arguments-in-c  .

Answer (score 0):

```
 test.exe @"C:\source path\" @"D:\destination"
```

The @ makes the string a verbatim literal.

In a verbatim string literal, the characters between the delimiters are interpreted verbatim, the only exception being a quote-escape-sequence.

Read more [here on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: @alexeilevenkov updated answer with a link from msdn

Comment: Indeed if it would be C# code, not command prompt. Have you tried to use it from command line? You'll get `@c:\source path"`, not `c:\source path\` as argument

Comment: @alexeilevenkov I apologize if I am wrong, but the question title says ".NET Console Application" not command line or batch?

Comment: May be confusing... But if you read question carefully (even before edits) - "The following command works fine..." - explains at least to me that problem with command line arguments from CMD, not any other way of invoking the tool. (BTW I think your sample is somewhat strange - with `Process.Start` it would make more sense).