# What is the canonical way of handling sys arguments in Python?

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, sys

Let's say I want to make a hashing script:

```
### some code here

def hashlib_based(path, htype='md5', block_size=2**16):
    hash = eval(htype)
    with open(path, 'rb') as f:
        for block in iter(lambda: f.read(block_size), ''):
            hash().update(block)
        f.close()
    return hash().hexdigest()

### some code here
```

As you can see, I have the opportunity to use different flags to allow me to change the hash type or the block size when I call the script from the command line (for example `./myscript.py -sha1 -b 512 some_file.ext`). The thing is, I don't have any clue on how should I do this in order to keep my code as clean and readable as possible. How do I deal with `sys.argv`?

First of all, how do I check if the user uses the correct flags? I need to do that in order to print out a **usage** message. Do I make a list with all the flags, then I check if the user uses one that is in that list?

Should I do all these things inside `main()` or should I do place them in a different function?

Should I construct my flags with a hyphen-minus in front of them (like this: -a, -b) or without one? To check if a certain flag is present in sys.argv, do I simply do something like:

```
if '-v' in sys.argv:
    verbose = True
```

?

Because sys.argv has indexes, what is the best way to ignore the order of the flags - or in other words,  should `./myscript.py -a -b` be the same as `./myscript.py -b -a`? While it certainly makes the job easier for the common user, is it common practice to do so?

[I saw something similar but for C#.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/491595/best-way-to-parse-command-line-arguments-in-c?rq=1) Is there a similar concept in Python?
The thing is, as simple as these things are, they get out of hands quickly - for me at least. I end up doing a mess. What is your approach to this problem?

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html

Comment: @MartijnPieters already covered the answer fully. I would just like to add http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/argparse.html :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For *really simple* use cases, such as checking the presence of one argument, you can do a check like you're showing, i.e.:

```
if '-v' in sys.argv: ...
```

which is the quick'n dirty way of checking arguments. But once your project gets a bit more serious, you definitely need to use an argument parsing library.

And there are a few ones to handle argument parsing: there is the now deprecated `getopt` (I won't give a link), the most common one is [argparse](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/argparse.html) which is included in any python distribution.

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-a', '--a-long', help='a help')
parser.add_argument('-b', '--b-long', help='b help')
args = parser.parse_args()
```

then you can call your `script -a -b` or `script -b -a` which will be equivalent. And for free, you've got `script -h` for free! :-)

Though, my preference is now over [docopt](http://docopt.org), imho, which is way simpler and more elegant, for the same example:

```
"""
My script.

usage:
    myscript -a | --along
    myscript -b | --blong

Options:
  -a --along     a help
  -b --blong     b help
"""

from docopt import docopt
arguments = docopt(__doc__, version='myscript 1.0')
print(arguments)
```

HTH

Comment: Thanks for pointing out docopt. Turns out I was trying to deal with all these problems without knowing of the existence of argument parsers. Makes me wonder how much else is there to learn.

Comment: And the good thing about docopt, it's that it works the same accross languages :-)