# Custom CMD Commands

Tags: c#, command-line-arguments

Is it possible to create custom Command Prompt parameters for an application written and compiled in Visual Studio C#. I want the users of my application to be able to do stuff in it just by command line.

For example, if the user types in CMD `application_name.exe -parameter` to do the code that was assigned to `parameter`.

Comment: There are built-in ways to do this of course, but I like to use [docopt.net](https://github.com/docopt/docopt.net). It's available in nuget.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes,  this is what `string[] args` is for in `Program.cs`.

The easiest way to ensure you have everything you need is to create your application from the Console Application template in Visual Studio.

To do this:

1. Go to File -> New Project...
2. Select `Console Application` from the list of available templates
3. Name your Solution
4. Hit OK to finish creating the Project

This will ensure you have all the references needed and that the `Program.cs` class is setup properly.

Here is a psuedo example of what you can do in the `Main` method of your program in order to accept parameters at the command line:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    if (args.Length <= 0) //Checking the Length helps avoid NullReferenceException at args[0]
    {
        //Default behavior of your program without parameters
    }
    else
    {
        if (args[0] == "/?")
        {
            //Show Help Manual
        }
        if (args[0] == "/d")
        {
            //Do something else
        }
        //etc
    }
}
```

Then at the command prompt the user can type:

```
yourProgamName.exe /?
yourProgramName.exe /d
```

As mentioned in an answer that was removed, there is a great library for handling complex Command Line options Here:

[NDesk Options](http://www.ndesk.org/Options)

Comment: You may want to so some checking that at least one arg was passed in. Perhaps change the first if statement to `if(args.Length == 0 || args[0] == "/?")` so it shows the help if you do `/?` or use no arguments at all.

Comment: If you want better/easier support of arguments and argument parsing check out NDesk Options - http://www.ndesk.org/Options

Comment: @Lloyd Yep, i know, but thought I would keep this a simple example as the OP seems to be a beginner.

Comment: This is what I was searching for. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I added a `Length` check for posterity (and avoiding a nullreference excepetion)

Comment: @EvanL Wasn't meant for you more a general FYI.

Comment: @Lloyd Agreed, and I love NDesk for this.  I will add your link to my answer.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I upvoted and I can't yet accept that answer, I have to wait 3 more minutes to accept an answer. :P

Comment: +1. Note that you'd better to start from "console application" template to get all working.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I will append my answer with that information, good point.

Answer (score 0):

That is what the "args" parameter is for in your main method.

If your users run "application_name.exe -parameter" then args[0] will be "-parameter". You can use this to branch your application to the correct code.

Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/491595/best-way-to-parse-command-line-arguments-in-c) to see examples and good libraries for handling lots of command line parameters/arguments.

Answer (score 0):

and if you don't have access to you `main()` for some reason, you can get your command line from `Environment.CommandLine`.