# c# split string with " exception

Tags: c#, split, arguments

I want to split a string into parts, to retrieve arguments.

I already made that function:

```
static private string getparam(string input, int index)
    {
        string[] arrparams = input.Split(' ');

        if (arrparams.Length <= index) return "";

        return arrparams[index];
    }
```

But when i pass an argument like:

upload C:\Visual Studio

it will see "C:\Visual" as the first argument and "Studio" as the second and split em.

Now i thought about making something like an exception in the Split-Function:
When the argument is given between quotes, it should ignore the spaces in it.

Then, when i pass the arg like this:
upload "C:\Visual Studio", the first argument should be C:\Visual Studio

So how could i implement this?

Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/491595/best-way-to-parse-command-line-arguments-in-c

Comment: Are you trying to parse parameters passed to a console app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> "I want to give commands from an online website. And my app is no command line app"

You can use Regex.

```
string[] arrparams = Regex.Matches(input, @"\""(?<token>.+?)\""|(?<token>[^\s]+)")
                    .Cast<Match>()
                    .Select(m => m.Groups["token"].Value)
                    .ToArray();
```

Comment: Wow! This one works. Thank you mate!

Answer (score 10):

The reason for the current behaviour is because *you are splitting on space*, so it shouldn't be a shock to find that it splits on space.

But the simpler fix is: don't do this. Let the runtime worry about it:

```
static void Main(string[] args) { ... }
```

and job done; all ready-parsed into separate tokens obeying the expected rules.

Comment: Alternatively you can use
```
Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()
```

Comment: I want to give commands from an online website. 
And my app is no command line app.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this with a **regex.split** method.

You code should be modified as

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
static private string getparam(string input, int index)
{
   <b>string pattern = @"[^\\s\"']+|\"([^\"]*)\"";
   string[] arrparams = Regex.Split(input,pattern);</b>
   if (arrparams.Length <= index) return "";
   return arrparams[index];
}
```

This bold code with match and split a space and when it is double quotes it will take as such.
Post back if you find any issues.

Thanks
Arun

Comment: `@"[^\\s\"']+|\"([^\"]*)\"";` is not a compilable string.. if you mean `"[^\\s\"']+|\"([^\"]*)\""` it doesn't do the work...