# Setting optional values using NDesk.Options

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013, ndesk.options

Using the accepted answer in [Best way to parse command line arguments in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/491595/best-way-to-parse-command-line-arguments-in-c) as your example, how can I make the 'r' or 'repeat' option only OPTIONALLY take a value and not REQUIRE it, and how can I set a default value if the value is not provided? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently you can do something like:

```
{ "r|repeat:", 
       "the number of {TIMES} to repeat the greeting.\n" + 
          "this must be an integer.",
        (int v) => repeat = v ?? 1 },
```

Where the default value is 1 if the value is not provided.

Comment: In this case, one may also the null-coalescing operator and write `repeat = v ?? 1`.

Comment: if you declare v as a string you will get "r" as value, consider that