# VS 2015 Form/Console Functionality in Application

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, application-design

This is more of a general theory question as I'm stuck on how to proceed since this is my first time developing an application...

I'm developing a reporting application in VS 2015 that requires two types of functionality. It needs to have a GUI so that users can interact with and create reports and those reports need to be scheduled via Windows Task Scheduler. I'm planning on using a Console Application for the scheduling portion. My question is, what would be the best way to implement this? As of right now I have two separate Projects in a single Solution. Is this the best route to take considering my needs or is there a better option that I'm not aware of? I've done some searching online but have not been able to find a valid solution. It's especially difficult since the scheduling portion needs to pull the application settings from the Windows Form Application.

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only reason you would need a console application would be if you actually needed a console interface. It doesn't sound like that's the case—the interface will be written in WinForms. Therefore, you don't actually need two separate applications. You can combine all the necessary functionality in a single executable.

The way to do this is by checking for command-line parameters that indicate whether the app should run interactively or headless. Probably, what you'll want to do is make the app run interactively when *no* command-line parameters are passed. This would be the normal case, the situation the user gets into when they double-click your app to launch it from Explorer.

When it comes time to schedule your app to run a task in the background (with Task Scheduler or anything else), you signal this by passing a special command-line parameter to your app. You can decide what this is, and you may need several of them if your app can do multiple things in the background. If configuration information/parameters need to (or can) be passed to the app to configure how it should perform the background task, you can pass these on the command line, too. Or, as you mention in the question, you could pull these settings from whatever was set/saved by the user the last time they ran the interactive version of the app.

The trick is just [checking for these command-line parameters in your application's `Main` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/main-and-command-args/). In the design I proposed, if there are no command-line parameters specified, then you just go ahead and create the main form like you normally would. If there *are* command-line parameters, then you need to parse them to see what action is being requested. Once you've parsed them and determined which background task should be run, you just run that background task—*without* ever creating/showing a form.

There are [lots of different solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/491595/best-way-to-parse-command-line-arguments-in-c) for parsing command-line parameters. Using a library would probably be the easiest way, and also give you the most features. But if you just needed something *really* simple, like a `/background` mode, then you could easily write the code for this yourself, without taking a dependency on a library or needing to learn how to use it.

So you could do all of this with a single project in a single solution if you wanted to. Or, you could split different aspects of the functionality out into different projects that compile to libraries (*e.g.*, DLLs), but still have only a single executable for simplicity.

Comment: Thank you very much for all of this detailed information.  You gave me a lot of great stuff to look into and it simplifies what I'm trying to do quite a bit.  Being able to keep all of my procedures into a single application is going to save me a lot of time and headache.