# Include regex match into separated string

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to parse command line options read from an already started process. The raw string looks like that
`-skipIntro -noSplash -cpuCount=7 -exThreads=7 -enableHT -malloc=tbb4malloc_bi_x64 -hugePages -maxmem=4096 -maxvram=2048 -world=empty -showScriptErrors -mod=`

Single parameters can have four different formats

- Parameter without value: `-skipIntro`
- Escaped parameter without value: `"-skipIntro"`
- Parameter with value: `-mod=foo`
- Escaped parameter with value: `"-mod=foo"` or `"-mod=b ar"`

Escaped parameters could include white spaces.
I want to split all parameters into an array of strings. The splitted parameters should include the prefix `-` respectively `"-`.

My regex looks like this:
`\s*[\"]*?-` which is working fine. However this also removes the prefix mentioned above. How can I include the prefix into the separated params array?

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/ZiCOPx/1)

Comment: The way is to describe parameters in a pattern and to find them. Don't try to split.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte how should I change the regex to match this?

Comment: Something like this: https://regex101.com/r/ZiCOPx/3

Comment: Using regex is not the best solution to parse args : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/491595/best-way-to-parse-command-line-arguments-in-c

Comment: @Indent this question is not about parsing command line options for the programm itself, it's about parsing command line options an other process was started with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a solution not splitting the string. Instead it returns matches.

```
(?<=^|\s)"-.*?"|-[^\s]*?(?=$|\s)
```

Explanation:

The general pattern `(?<=prefix)find(?=suffix)` is used that matches a position between a prefix and a suffix. Where

Prefix is: `^|\s`       beginning of string or space character.
Suffix is: `$|\s`       end of string or space character.

Find: `"-.*?"|-[^\s]*?` finds either `"-`, followed by any characters, followed by `"`
OR
`-`, followed by any character except a space character.
Both variants with as few characters as possible (indicated by `?`).

```
string pattern = @"(?<=^|\s)""-.*?""|-[^\s]*?(?=$|\s)";
string input = "-skipIntro \"-skipIntro\" -noSplash \"-mod=foo\" \"-mod=b ar\" -cpuCount=7";
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);
foreach (Match match in matches) {
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
}
```

Note that in verbatim strings `@"..."`, double quotes `"` are espcaped by doubling them.

Answer (score 0):

would that regex work for what you're trying to achieve ?

```
((\")?-.*?(?(2)\"|(\s|$)))
```

[Here's a fork of your Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/KXvsgq/1)

Note that the first group captures every option, but you're gonna have to trim it as it keeps the following one whitespace that separates the options. That's the best I could do to keep the surrounding quotes.