# split string with string and retrieve value in c#

Tags: c#

```
string mystring = "-p \"C:\\Users\\mplususer\\Documents\\SharpDevelop Projects\\test\\test\\bin\\Debug\\test.exe\" -t False -r TestRun"
```

i have to extract from mystring whatever in front of command **-r** here is "**Testrun**"

```
string[] value = mystring .Split(new string[] { "\"-r " }, StringSplitOptions.None);
                if (value.Length != 0)
                {
                    runConfig = value[1].Replace("\"", "");
                }
```

Comment: Ok. What is your question then?

Comment: Is this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/491595/best-way-to-parse-command-line-arguments-in-c) answer your question?

Comment: From path i have to retrieve value TestRun (-r is commnd)

Comment: This is not a question. Explain what is wrong with your current implementation. Is that command ALWAYS at the end of the string or may vary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use this `String.Split` version:

```
string[] value = mystring.Split(new string[] {" -r " }, 2, StringSplitOptions.None);
string runConfig = value.Last().Split()[0];
```

The second `Split` is just for the case that there are other parameters after the `-r` possible.