# Initializing a dictionary of function pointers and limits in C#

Tags: c#, dictionary, command-line

I am working with a group to make a command line tool that takes a lot of sub commands - e.g.:

```
cmdtool.exe foo 1 2 3
```

or

```
cmdtool.exe bar 9 zombies
```

Currently it is implemented with a long and ugly list of

```
else if (command == "foo")
{
    if (argLength < 3)
    {
        Console.Error.WriteLine("Error: not enough args for foo");
        errorCode = ExitCode.Error;
    }
    else
    {
        // Do something useful
    }
}
else if (command == "bar")
// repeat everything from foo
```

My issue with that is that there is a lot of duplicate code and no good overview of all our subcommands
I know how I would do it in python:

```
def commandFoo(args):
    return DoFooStuff(args)

def commandBar(args):
    return DoBarStuff(args)

REGULAR_COMMANDS = {
    "foo": [1, 3, commandFoo],
    "bar": [2, 2, commandBar]
}

def evaluateCommand(cmdString, args):
    if cmdString not in REGULAR_COMMANDS:
        print("Unknown command:", cmdString)
        return False
    lower = REGULAR_COMMANDS[cmdString][0]
    upper = REGULAR_COMMANDS[cmdString][1]
    if not lower <= len(args) <= upper:
        print("Wrong number of args for:", cmdString)
        return False
    func = REGULAR_COMMANDS[cmdString][2]
    return func(args)
```

But how do I do that nicely in C#?

I have come close with this:

```
private static int CommandFoo(string[] args)
{
    Console.Error.WriteLine("FooFOO");
    return (int)ExitCode.Success;
}
private static int CommandBar(string[] args)
{
    Console.Error.WriteLine("BarBAR");
    return (int)ExitCode.Error;
}
private static Dictionary<string, List<object>> m_dCommandFuncs = new Dictionary<string, List<object>> {
    { "foo", {1, 3, CommandFoo}},
    { "bar", {2, 2, CommandBar}}
};
```

But the syntax for initializing my lookup table is not correct and when I try to correct it, it gets ugly and still doesn't compile.

Is this a limitation in the C# syntax? - that I cannot initialize dictionaries and lists in a pretty way?

How would a C# expert go about this?

**Complete Solution as given by @mcbr :**

```
delegate int Command(string[] args);

private static int CommandFoo(string[] args)
{
    Console.Error.WriteLine("FooFOO");
    return (int)ExitCode.Success;
}
private static int CommandBar(string[] args)
{
    Console.Error.WriteLine("BarBAR");
    return (int)ExitCode.Error;
}

private static Dictionary<string, List<object>> m_dCommandFuncs = new Dictionary<string, List<object>> {
    { "foo", new List<object>{1, 3, (Command) CommandFoo}},
    { "bar", new List<object>{2, 2, (Command) CommandBar}}
};


if (m_dCommandFuncs.ContainsKey(command))
{
    List<object> lLimitsAndFunc = m_dCommandFuncs[command];
    int lowerLimit = (int)lLimitsAndFunc[0];
    int upperLimit = (int)lLimitsAndFunc[1];
    Command commandFunc = (Command) lLimitsAndFunc[2];
    if (argLength < lowerLimit || argLength > upperLimit)
    {
        Console.Error.WriteLine("error: {0}, wrong number of arguments", command);
        exitCode = (int)ExitCode.Error;
    }
    else
    {
        var segment = new ArraySegment<string>(args, 1, (1 + upperLimit - lowerLimit));
        exitCode = commandFunc(segment.ToArray<string>());
    }
}
```

I also looked into various Nuget packages, but they add more clutter than benefits IMHO

Comment: `"I am working with a group to make a command line tool that takes a lot of sub commands"` <= Have you already looked for an existing tool / wrapper? There are plenty available, just search NuGet. See this previous question on [so] : [Best way to parse command line arguments in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/491595/1260204)

Comment: I'd use an arguments parser, such as [NDesk.Options](http://www.ndesk.org/Options)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a [delegate type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/delegate) `delegate int Command(string[] args);`
and initialize the dictionary like this:

```
    private static Dictionary<string, List<object>> m_dCommandFuncs = new Dictionary<string, List<object>>
    {
        { "foo", new List<object>{1, 3, (Command)CommandFoo}},
        { "bar", new List<object>{2, 2, (Command)CommandBar}}
    };
```

As others have said you have to explicitly write that you want new list. The cast is needed because the compiler complains that it's unable to convert `method group` to `object`. You can also cast to `Func<string[],int>`. To avoid using `List<object>` you should define new class like this:

```
    class CommandConfig
    {
        public int Lower { get; set; }
        public int Upper { get; set; }
        public Command Command { get; set; }
    }
    private static Dictionary<string, CommandConfig> m_dCommandFuncs2 = new Dictionary<string, CommandConfig>
    {
        {"foo", new CommandConfig {Lower = 1, Upper = 3, Command = CommandFoo}},
        {"bar", new CommandConfig {Lower = 2, Upper = 2, Command = CommandBar}}
    };
```

`Command` is still the delegate type.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that C# complex object/dictionary initialization is not as simple as in other languages. I think you only need one tweak to make your attempt work, however:

```
private static Dictionary<string, List<object>> m_dCommandFuncs = new Dictionary<string, List<object>> {
    { "foo", new List<object>{1, 3, CommandFoo}},
    { "bar", new List<object>{2, 2, CommandBar}}
};
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a go. Thought I'd tried it before - but let me just double check

Comment: With the `delegate type` mentioned by @mcbr, this will work. Thanks.