# How to pass/check for specified arguments?

Tags: c#

I'm currently writing a C# console application and would like to give the user the ability to chose what feature to be executed. For example, when I start `MyApp.exe -help` the help should show, or when I start `MyApp.exe -shutdown` the computer should shutdown. How do I pass/check that?

My current code doesn't seem to work:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
        if (args.Equals("-help"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Some help here...");
        }
}
```

Comment: Clue: `args` is an _array_. And then read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/main-and-command-args/command-line-arguments or https://www.dotnetperls.com/main

Comment: It might be best to find a command line argument parser library. Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/491595/best-way-to-parse-command-line-arguments-in-c) for some ideas. It appears that there's a [Microsoft one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2019/march/net-parse-the-command-line-with-system-commandline).

Comment: @ADyson: I have already read this, but it doesn't really help me.

Comment: `args.Equals("-help")` checks if the array object is equal to `-help`, not if one of its items equals `-help`. How might you achieve the latter (which is what you want)?

Comment: Why doesn't it help? Look more carefully at how they access a specific argument value, versus how you've done it. As John says, you're testing the entire array, not any specific item within it. This is not unique to command line arguments, it's the same for any array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*args* is an array so you need to look for *-help* occurrence in it. You can achieve it using [String.Contains()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.contains?view=netframework-4.8) method.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    if (args.Contains("-help"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Some help here...");
    }
}
```

Comment: @Daruk you're right, String.Contains() sits in System namespace. I'll fix my answer.

Comment: `args` is an array, it isn't a string

Answer (score 2):

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ProcesArguments(args);
    }

    static void ProcesArguments(string[] parameters)
    {
        foreach (var parameter in parameters)
        {
            switch (parameter.ToLower())
            {
                case "-help":
                    DisplayHelp();
                    break;
                case "-reboot":
                    RebootComputer();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    static void DisplayHelp()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Syntax: {System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName} <Parameter>");
        // ...
    }

    static void RebootComputer()
    {
        // ...
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Args is an array, so you have to reference the argument by its index.  So `args[0]` corresponds to the first argument passed in.  In addition, check the array length first to ensure an argument was even provided before you try to access it.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    if (args.Length > 0 && args[0] == "-help")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Some help here...");
    }
}
```