# Getting parameters after argument in command line

Tags: c#, .net-core, command-line, command-line-arguments

Hi so I am trying to get the two values after user input --dimensions.

For example when I do: `dotnet app.dll --dimensions 1 2` (In command line)

It prints

```
1
2
```

Which is the result I'm after.

But when I do: `dotnet app.dll --test --dimensions 1 2`

It returns `hi`, meaning that `--test` worked. But returns an error for `--dimensions`

```
hi
Unhandled exception. System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
   at System.Number.ThrowOverflowOrFormatException(ParsingStatus status, TypeCode type)
   at System.String.System.IConvertible.ToInt32(IFormatProvider provider)
   at System.Convert.ToInt32(Object value)
   at MainClass.Main(String[] args)
```

I don't want the argument to only work if its the first argument given. That is why I added `--test` before `--dimensions`

I want it to work when the argument `--dimensions` is placed anywhere.

For example `dotnet app.dll --test --test --dimensions 1 2 --test`

Which should return

```
hi
hi
1
2
hi
```

Im new with this as well :( Sorry.

Code:

```
using System;

class MainClass
{
    private static int value1, value2;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        foreach (string value in args)
        {
            int for_dimensions = 0;

            string testing = "--test";

            if (value == "--dimensions" && args.Length >= for_dimensions + 2)
            {
                object test1 = args.GetValue(for_dimensions+1);
                value1 = Convert.ToInt32(test1);
                    
                object test2 = args.GetValue(for_dimensions + 2);
                value2 = Convert.ToInt32(test2);

                Console.WriteLine(value1);
                Console.WriteLine(value2);
            }

            if (value == testing)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("hi");
            }
            
        }
        
    }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Already asked a few hours ago and oriented to a question about commandline parsers... Deleted and reposted. Know that doing that is annoying, espacially for whose taked time to help. You should improve your original question and/or wait for more help if needed, if you want help.

Comment: Well sorry, but https://stackoverflow.com/questions/491595/best-way-to-parse-command-line-arguments-in-c this did not help me much as it is too complex to what I am learning so far, as I said before, I am new and this concepts are very hard for me to understand.

Comment: You should use a standardized https://www.google.com/search?q=github+c%23+commandline+parser especially for complicated arguments.

Comment: What if I create a function that will take the command line argument as input, but how will I return those values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use an existing command line parser framework (which I highly recommend due to higher flexibility) for example [this](https://github.com/commandlineparser/commandline) one, you can achieve your desired output like this:

```
// Find array index of "--dimensions"
var argIndex = Array.IndexOf(args, "--dimensions");

// Get remaining array size (all items after "--dimensions")
var subArraySize = args.Length - argIndex - 1;
string[] subArray = new string[subArraySize];

// Put all remaining items (all items after "--dimensions") into new array
Array.Copy(args, argIndex + 1, subArray, 0, subArraySize);

// Iterate over all items after "--dimensions"
var results = new List<int>();
foreach(var entry in subArray)
{
    // Check if the item is another command, if so we are finished
    if(entry.StartsWith('-'))
        break;
    
    // Item isn't a command, try to parse it to int and if successful add to result set
    if(int.TryParse(entry, out var numEntry))
        results.Add(numEntry);
}
```

To output the found parameters for "--dimensions" just iterate over `results`:

```
foreach(var result in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

With this implementation you can process a variable amount of dimension inputs. Either like in your example 1 and 2, or just 1 or 1, 2 and 3 for example:

> dotnet app.dll --test --test --dimensions 1 2 --test
> dotnet app.dll --test --test --dimensions 1 --test
> dotnet app.dll --test --test --dimensions 1 2 3 --test

Comment: Thank you so much, I will try this one :). and we were told not to use an existing command line parser framework (I did not even know those existed).

Comment: Hi, may I be able to ask two more questions, sorry for the hassle, Im just really not good with this. How can I limit it to only two entries after `--dimensions`? How can I access or store those two entries for later use? Thank you again and sorry if I'm being annoying.

Comment: @j_m To store the entries you could assign them to your already existing variables `value1` and `value2` like this: `value1 = results[0]` and `value2 = results[1]`. When accessing values with the indexer `[<index>]` you have to make sure the item at the index position you want to access does exist, otherwise an exception will be thrown. Saving the entries like this also makes limiting the result set to two entries unnecessary.